# Cannot Replace string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]". I need to remove all square brackets. For this I used the replace function in Javascript.

```
var str = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/[[/g,''); //not working
var str2 = str1.replace(/]]/g,''); //working
```

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Doh! I just realized that of course this has been asked before. I searched for "replace square bracket javascript site:stackoverflow.com" to find the earlier copy, FWIW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a regular expression, the `[` has a special meaning (it starts a "character class" where you can say `[abc]`, which matches `a`, `b`, or `c`).

To make it not special, put a backslash in front of it to escape it:

```js
var str = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/\[\[/g,'');
var str2 = str1.replace(/]]/g,'');
snippet.log("str = " + str);
snippet.log("str1 = " + str1);
snippet.log("str2 = " + str2);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

And in fact, a character class could help here, because you want to replace both `[` and `]`, so:

```js
var str = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/[\[\]]/g,'');
snippet.log("str = " + str);
snippet.log("str1 = " + str1);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

In the regex `/[\[\]]/g`, the first `[` and the last `]` mark the character class, and the `\[` and `\]` inside are the literal characters `[` and `]`. (You don't technically need to escape the `[` *inside* a character class, but I have to admit I tend to for...I don't know...clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Add `\` before `[`,

```js
var str  = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/\[\[/g,'');
console.log(str1);
```

You need escape `[` because `[` is [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
var str  = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/\[\[/g,'').replace(/\]\]/g,'');
alert(str1);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLu81qnw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions the `[`-character signifies the start of a character group that can match any character within that group. You'll need to escape the `[` using backslash like so `\[`.

`var str = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/\[/g,'');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove open and close square bracket, you can try this

```
"[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]".replace(/\[|\]/g, "")
```

Square bracket is for character class `[]`, If you want to match it you have to escape it with backslash in the pattern. And pipe line `|` is saying or, so match open square bracket or close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those `[` `]` by adding a `\` in front of them since they are special characters in a regular expression. In your case, you want to delete all square brackets in your string. It means you need to capture them all. In order to do so, you need to define a set of those characters.

In a regular expression `[]` defines a set of characters you want to capture. In your case, you want to capture `[` and `]` and since they are special characters, you first need to escape them.

So what you want is:

```
var str  = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
var str1 = str.replace(/[\[\]]/g,'');
console.log(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 var str  = "[[String1]],[[String2]],[[String3]]";
 var str1="",str2="";
 str = str.split(",");

 for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
 {
 str[i] = str[i].replace("[[","");
 str[i] = str[i].replace("]]","");
 if(i != (str.length-1))
 {
 str1 = str1+str[i]+",";
 }
 else
 {
 str1 = str1+str[i];
 }
 }

 alert(str1);
```